# Global exception handler for Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

Is it possible to have a global exception handler for Azure Functions .Net C# project?

We'd like to have a centralized place to log exceptions to Rollbar.

Comment: Would exception filter work for you? https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters

Comment: FunctionFilters are still in preview as of this writing, so not a great workaround IMO...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible now with the new out-of-process (= isolated) model by [defining your own middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware).
Here, in the "samples" folder of the "azure-functions-dotnet-worker" repository, I also found a sample for [ExceptionHandlingMiddleware](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/samples/CustomMiddleware/ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.cs).

Unfortunately, related content is too big to include it in the answer, but I hope I put enough keywords to find the thing.

Answer (score 11):

I'm also waiting for test feature but for now, I have written my aspect (AOP) for logging/Exception handling. I have many functions but didn't write single try-catch for exception handling.

I'm using [MrAdvice](https://github.com/ArxOne/MrAdvice) for AOP

**Aspect**

```
public class LoggerAspectAttribute : Attribute, IMethodAsyncAdvice
{
    public async Task Advise(MethodAsyncAdviceContext context)
    {
        ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger();
        RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry { Name = context.TargetType.Name };
        IOperationHolder<RequestTelemetry> operation = log.TelemetryClient.StartOperation(requestTelemetry);
        operation.Telemetry.Success = true;
        log.Info($"{context.TargetType.Name} trigger");

        try
        {
            await context.ProceedAsync(); // this calls the original method
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            operation.Telemetry.Success = false;
            log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            log.Info($"{context.TargetType.Name} completed.");
            log.TelemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
        }
    }
}
```

**Function**

```
public static class AlertFunction
{
    [LoggerAspect]
    [FunctionName("AlertFunction")]
    public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("%AlertEventHub%", Connection = "AlertEventHubConnection", ConsumerGroup = "%AlertEventHubConsumerGroup%")]EventData eventMessage,
        [Inject]IEventService eventService, [Inject]ILog log)
    {
        log.Verbose($"Event PartitionKey {eventMessage.PartitionKey}, Offset {eventMessage.Offset} and SequenceNumber {eventMessage.SequenceNumber}");
        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventMessage.GetBytes());
        log.Verbose(message);
        await eventService.FilterAlertEventAsync(message);
    }
}
```

hope it will give some idea!

Comment: Hello, only issue here is that if you use dependency injection and that it fails to create a service, you won't have any logs ! Anyway, thanks for the idea !

Comment: @JonathanANTOINE As with MrAdvice is not built upon dependency injection but AOP this should not be a problem.

Comment: How does LogManager,GetLogger() obtain the dependency? Struggling to understand how to inject dependencies into the aspects.

Answer (score 3):

For now this feature is not available, you could go to the [feedback page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/20308660-global-exception-handler#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D) upvote the feature to indicate your request.

However you still could use Azure Function with Application Insights, about details you could refer to this doc: [Monitor Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring).

Comment: Have there been any updates about this? Is there a way to "handle" unhandled exceptions with Azure functions using dotnet with something like Sentry?

Comment: the feedback page link is dead, shows you how much MSFT cares about your feedback